# Regular expression to validate a string

Tags: c#, regex

What should be the regular expression if i need to show the error if the string contains character other than  letters, digits, blank, underscore (_), dash (-), dollar sign ($), at sign (@),open curly brace ({), close curly brace (}) and pound sign (#)

```
Regex.IsMatch(myString, ?????????, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\ _#\-\$\{\}@]*$
```

PS : Usefull tool to create REGEX : https://www.debuggex.com/